# Best approach on how read from terminal? Kattis counting stars

Tags: javascript, node.js, input

Im trying to dig into this kattis.com challenge called [counting stars](https://open.kattis.com/problems/countingstars) using NodeJs. If you see the input example, it always start with a line of two integers, the first one represents the number of rows, the second one represents the numbers of columns per row, there are a lot of examples with C and Java, but I want to solve this with JS (Nodejs). How I can read from the terminal and iterate line by line, I tried with the next code

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

var lines = [];
rl.on('line', line => {
  lines.push(line);
  console.log(lines);
});
```

But for some reason, if I input this sample

```
3 10
#-########
----------
#-########
```

It only show me the first 3 lines, also tried with this line `while (line = readline()) {}`, but also not working because of `readline isn't a function`

In Java they use a class of `Scanner(System.in);`, and probably that class make things easier

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. The missing piece is adding code to distinguish test cases. The easiest option might be to slurp all of the lines into an array, listen to `"close"` on the readline and then process everything synchronously in one go, chunking out tests based on the `^\d+ \d+$` pattern.

However, this approach is memory-unfriendly, so I'd prefer to only consume one test case at a time, solve it in isolation, then free the memory:

```js
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.on("line", line => {
    if (/^\d+ \d+$/g.test(line)) {
      if (lines.length) {
        solve(lines, id++);
        lines.length = 0;
      }
    }
    else {
      lines.push(line);
    }
  })
  .on("close", () => solve(lines, id));

let id = 1;
const lines = [];

const solve = (grid, id) => {
  let count = 0;

  // your algorithm here

  console.log(`Case ${id}: ${count}`);
};
```

See also:

- [Getting input in Kattis challenges - readline js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477386/getting-input-in-kattis-challenges-readline-js/69559880#69559880)
- [Kattis - readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536552/kattis-readline/72549523#72549523) *(deleted thread--10k+ rep to view)*
- [How to line split in Kattis problem-solving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012014/how-to-line-split-in-kattis-problem-solving/69562323#69562323)
- [using readline stdin in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855733/using-readline-stdin-in-node-js/69562068#69562068)
- [Reading multiple lines in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850027/reading-multiple-lines-in-node-js/69562205#69562205)