# Reading two strings using readline

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a hard time undestanding how to use the readline library from NodeJS to read two different strings for a Kattis challenge.

See, in [their documentation](https://open.kattis.com/help/javascript) there's the following example:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var nums = line.split(' ');
    var a = parseInt(nums[0]);
    var b = parseInt(nums[1]);
    /*Solve the test case and output the answer*/
});
```

I need to read two strings and then manipulate them. I've already tried doing:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

var string1 = '';
var string2 = '';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var string1 = line;
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    var string2 = line;
});

//manipulating strings...
```

and even:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

var string1 = '';
var string2 = '';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('', (answer) => {
    var string1 = answer;
});

rl.question('', (line) => {
    var string2 = answer;
});

//manipulating strings...
```

But I keep getting a Run time error. What am I doing wrong, exactly?

Comment: You're getting a runtime error because you're assigning a variable in an asynchronous scope (in the callback for `rl.on('line',..` or `rl.question(..`) and trying to access it later synchronously. I'd recommend reading up on asynchronous JavaScript before proceeding with this challenge, or any JS scripting that might involve it.

Comment: Additionally, although it doesn't produce an error, it is very bad style and reduces readability to re-declare variables using `var` like you do in `var string1 = answer;` - at first I thought you were declaring a variable in one scope and trying to use it in another.

Comment: What challenge are you doing? Many possible dupes here explaining how to read lines in JS for Kattis: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69559880/6243352), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562323/6243352), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72549523/6243352), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562068/6243352), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562205/6243352)