# using readline stdin in node.js

Tags: node.js, readline

I am working on [this problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/carrots) in kattis where I need to get the second integer inputted on the first line. The integers can be 1-999. In the example input below, I need to display 80:

```
2 80
carrots
bunnies
```

Here is my code:

```
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
  
rl.on("line", (line) => {
    let inputData = line;
    console.log(inputData)
});
```

In the console log inputData, it displays the whole input. I also tried to split the line using let inputData = line.split(' '); and the results werebut still I don't know how to be able to get 80 :

```
[ '2', '80' ]
[ 'carrots' ]
[ 'bunnies' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a string you can use `str.split(" ")` (where str is a string). You would get an array of strings like `['2','80']` from which you can access the first element.

eg:

```
let inputData = line.split(" ")
console.log(inputData[1]);
//output: 80
```

Comment: this is my code now let inputData = line.split(' '); console.log(inputData[1]) but the output is 80
undefined
undefined

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the question asks you to parse and print the second number from the first line ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64855854/6243352) shows how to `split` a string and pick an index), but then ignore all remaining lines.

If you don't de-register your `.on("line", ...)` handler, it'll throw errors or print bad output on subsequent lines.

One approach is to use `.once` rather than `.on` to de-register the handler after the first line is consumed:

```js
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
  
rl.once("line", line => console.log(line.split(/ +/).pop()));
```

Now, normally with Kattis problems, you'll want to consume the rest of the data as well. See [Getting input in Kattis challenges - readline js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477386/getting-input-in-kattis-challenges-readline-js/69559880#69559880) for how to do this.